# Randomly select multiple items from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, random

I want to have an array with different words and phrases and randomly generate around five of these on page refresh. How would I go about doing this in javascript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-random-value-from-an-array

Comment: Where are you stuck? Do you not know how to generate a random number from 0-n? Do you know know how to loop to get five of them? Do you not know how to get the element from the array once you have a random index?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the array length and run a for loop to do this with Math.random():

```
var randomNums = [];
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
    int x = myArray[Math.random()*(myArray.length-1)];
    if(!randomNums.contains(x)){
        randomNums.push(x);
    }
}
```

randomNums should then be an array with five random values from your other array

Comment: This could result in duplicates.

Comment: @torazaburo check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Run through a loop.
Each time remove 1 object from your original array and put it into a new one
If you want to keep your original array, you can make a copy.

```
var myArray = [];
var myNewArray = [];
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    myNewArray.push(myArray.splice(Math.random()*(myArray.length-1),1).pop());
}
```

You could also create an array with 5 random numbers between 0 and myArray.length-1. Then you have to check after each random number generation, if the generated number is already in the array.

```
var indexArr = [];
while (indexArr.length < 5) {
    var rndIndex = Math.random()*(myArray.length-1);
    if (indexArr.indexOf(rndIndex) == -1) // if rndIndex is not in indexArr
        indexArr.push(rndIndex);
}
```

Then you can use the indexArray to return 5 random elements from your original array.